# как построить маршрут от текущего местоположения до latitude, longitude?

Tags: java, android, карты

подскажите как сделать так чтобы он мне не точку показал по координатам, а построил маршрут от текущего местоположения до latitude, longitude. На данный момент я сделал так:

```
  private void showMap(Uri geoLocation) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(geoLocation);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

> Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь нажал на кнопку и ему предложило выбрать
>   какую карту ему открыть, после: от текущего местоположения до выбранной
>   точки ему строило бы маршрут

**Uri генерирую так:**

```
Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude);
```

Есть ли какая - нибудь готовая библиотека?

Узнать все установленные приложения на телефоне можно с помощью: `getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0)`

Я могу узнать приложения карты установленные на мобильном. А как теперь предложить пользователю выбрать одно из них?

Comment: Те кто кидал тревогу, что вам не понятно?!

Comment: выбрать то приложение не так сложно есть `Intent.createChooser`, а вот передать туда различные данные непонятно как

Comment: скорее всего вам нужно кастомное что-то писать, выводить диалоговое окно, в нём рисовать кнопки приложений и далее также вручную указывать интент

Comment: @Komdosh наверное только так, эх(

Comment: Попробуйте написать похожий вопрос на английский стековерфлоу, там коммьюнитит всё таки побольше, может там знают

Comment: @Komdosh попробую в гите поискать, если нет. буду свое реализовывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Uri geoLocation  = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=55.76009,37.648801");

switch(typeOfMap){
  case GOOGLE: 
    geoLocation = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=55.76009,37.648801");
  break;
  case YANDEX:
    geoLocation = Uri.parse("yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?rtext=55.745719,37.604337~55.76009,37.648801&rtt=mt");
   break;
}

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoLocation);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: это ж гугловская откроется, меня это не интересует

Comment: тогда вам нужно перефразировать вопрос, так как 2 человека не могли его понять одинаково неправильно

Comment: Читайте внимательно: "Так же мне необходимо, чтобы пользователю дать возможность выбора какую карту ему открыть из установленных у него приложений. (т.е конкретно гугловская, карта яндекса меня не устраивает)."

Comment: ну так, с точки зрения русского языка фраза "т.е конкретно гугловская, карта яндекса меня не устраивает", вызывает противоречие, так как требуете гугловскую карту и утверждаете, что карта яндекс вам не подходит

Comment: мне нужно чтобы пользователь нажал на кнопку и ему предложило выбрать какую карту ему открыть, после от текущего местоположения до выбранной точки ему строил бы маршрут

Comment: яндекс навигатор и гугл карты предлагает, а вот например 2гис нет.

Comment: тогда в таком случае 2гис не выберется или какая-нибудь другая мапа)))

Comment: а это зависит уже от api

Comment: понимаю, поэтому я и спрашиваю библиотеку готовую

Comment: не, тут скорее надо свой велосипед делать, не встречал такие библиотеки, хотя с картами работал

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Пример из [матчасти](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents):

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: это ж гугловская откроется, меня это не интересует

Comment: В вопросе написано, что интересует "конкретно гугловская".

Comment: не интересует...